# Amazon Polly in Alexa Skill?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-polly

Is it possible to use amazon Polly in an Alexa Skill to deliver for instance an 2 language response in an translation or otherwise multilingual context?
And if yes, who has experiences with using this service from a lambda function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE:** According to the [helpful comment by Julian H](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43863489/amazon-polly-in-alexa-skill/43882914?noredirect=1#comment104508372_43882914) this answer has been updated to reflect the latest changes to Polly. **Polly is now able to be used without conversion with Alexa, and steps 7-9 below are no longer necessary.**

I have updated the following steps to reflect the new process of using Polly w/ Alexa via lambda function based on the project [alexa-meets-polly.](https://github.com/KayLerch/alexa-meets-polly/blob/master/README.md)

---

From alexa-meets-polly:

> 1. User speaks to an Alexa device and asks for e.g. "What is "Good Morning" in Polish?"
> 2. NLU of Alexa triggers the Translate-intent and passes in a language-slot with value Polish and a term-slot having the value Good
>      Morning. An AWS Lambda function whose code is contained in this Repo
>      implements a Speechlet that handles the request and returns the
>      translation.
> 3. Before this skill uses the translation API and TTS service of Polly, it first looks into its own dictionary where all the previous
>      translations are stored. If it finds a record for Good Morning in
>      Polish in the database it will skip the entire round-trip (step 4 to
>      9) and uses the S3 audio-file referenced in the Dynamo record (learn
>      how it got there in step 10.)
> 4. However, if Good Morning in Polish has never been translated before the skill requests Good Morning in Polish from Microsoft Translator
>      API (or interchangeably from Google Translate).
> 5. The returned translation is then passed to AWS Polly. Polly responds with an MP3 bitstream with the spoken translation.
> 6. The stream is persisted in AWS S3 as an mp3-file.
>
> 7.-9. No custom conversion of Polly-mp3 necessary anymore as it's now aligned to Alexa requirements.
>
> 10. Finally, a record is created for Good Morning in Polish in the Dynamo dictionary. Another record that references the new dictionary
>       entry is created for the user so Alexa keeps in mind the last
>       translation. This is how a user can request Alexa to repeat the most
>       recent translation.
> 11. The skill creates the output-speech text and squeezes in an audio-SSML tag with the mp3-url.
> 12. Output-speech is returned to the Alexa device. Alexa speaks and plays back the translated text with one of Polly's voices. A card is
>       returned to the Alexa app providing the written translation.

Comment: Thank you. Great Explanation!

Comment: I second KayLerch's alexa-meets-polly example, this is a solid example.

Comment: UPDATE I checked the useful alexa-meets-polly 2 Dec 2019 and Alexa / Polly's mp3 output are now sync: "No custom conversion of Polly-mp3 necessary anymore as it's now aligned to Alexa requirements."